# I can't use Windows PowerShell commands

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

I'm new to Windows PowerShell and i can't seem to give command correctly.
I want to Import NetAdapter module.
But i get the error "'Import-ModuleNetAdapter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script, file or operable program.".

```
 - List item
 - Import-ModuleNetAdapter
 - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Import-ModuleNetAdapter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException 
 - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I will use the module for the sole purpose of self-defense.
How to list commands from the cmdlet?

Comment: Space is missing.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you for your response, could you please specify on what i should have done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Import-Module`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-6) is the cmdlet which takes as a parameter the name of the module to import. As noted by PetSerAI in the comments, you must separate the cmdlet name from the parameter with a space:

```
Import-Module NetAdapter
```

You should then see something like this:

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetAdapter                          {Disable-NetAdapter, Disable-NetAdapterBinding, Disable-Ne...
```

Typing `Import-ModuleNetAdapter` causes PowerShell to look for a cmdlet literally named `Import-ModuleNetAdapter`, which does not exist, producing the `CommandNotFoundException` you see.